# How to get list of software installed on my windows for second usre?

Tags: windows

Mistakenly I set 500% resoultion for my account.

I have create a new account for getting it's worked. Can someone know how to get list of software I already have installed.

When  I logged in from new account on my computer I see their is no list of application shown in the start menu.

Comment: If you were to ask a question about how to fix your resolution on your main again, you could probably find an answer for that, and save you the trouble of dealing with a second account.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Start>Control Panel>Add/Remove Software

This should give you a full list of programs installed.

Comment: Sorry, Maybe I create a confusion.Actually I want to get them all listed in my start menu. Can you please know the way. I have manually add some of them but not know how I am able to listen them all in new start menu.